# Is the Logitech G11 fully supported with Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, compatibility, logitech-keyboard

I went to Logitech's support page here:

http://logitech-en-amr.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/32425#Keyboards

It lists the G11 as a keyboard that works with Windows 8, but it throws in this confusing blurb:

The products listed here:

- Have only basic functionality on Windows RT. Software and app support aren't available for this platform.
- Will provide basic navigation in Windows 8 style UI. Features programmed in SetPoint software may not function in this mode.

What is meant by those two bullets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first field refers to an OS you probably aren't running, [Windows RT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_RT). It's Windows for ARM processors such as the [Surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Surface#Surface_with_Windows_RT) tablet.

The second field refers to applications running in the new UI called "[Modern UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_UI_%28design_language%29)", formerly known as "Metro" - it's those tiles and programs you can start from the menu you get when you hit the Windows Key on your PC. In fact, that entire environment is what the second bit is talking about. So what they're saying is that when you're running a Modern UI application (like Angry Birds or a media player, etc.) the G11's software might not work with that.